# Android showDividers not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to put dividers between my textviews and the button but nothing is visible. Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/quizid1"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Quiz"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/quiz_intro"
        android:textSize="33sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="@color/holo_blue_dark"         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/quiz_intro2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="@string/quiz_intro3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/go_btn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using API 14 so i dont think that is the problem. I am using the holo dark theme in the app.Even if i try to use button bar style which should automatically add a divider, that also doesnt create a divider.
What could be the issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What do you wanna do by setting dividers in `RelativeLayout`?
Dividers are defined for `ListView` but not for `RelativeLayout`.

If you want to separate views in your layout just create divider view (in layout folder) and include it in your parent layout:

Horizontal divider:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/divider_color" />
```

Vertical divider:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/divider_color" />
```

And then:

```
<include layout="@layout/divider_horizontal" />
```

Comment: yes i am aware of the fact that divider is used in listview. But they can also be used in relative layout in case i am using something like borderless button to demarcate touch areas.I think the code i have used is for using default dividers provided with the holo theme rather than creating my own so it should function similar to your answer.

Comment: @ShivamBhalla you ca use a LinearLayout and show dividers. Also its for api 11 and above.

Comment: @Raghunandan can i not do it with relative layout ? Yes my api level is 14 so that wont be a problem.

Comment: @ShivamBhalla from what i see in the docs it looks like no unless i am missing something in  the docs.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html and linear layout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

Comment: @ShivamBhalla using linear layout it will look like http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=nccwht&s=5. for clarity if you need i can post it as an answer.